# attributedTextでの変更点をNSUserDefaultで保存したい。

Tags: ios, objective-c

UITextViewをattributedTextで部分的に色付けが可能なメモ帳を作成しているのですが、
attributedTextで加えた変更をUserDefaultに保存したいのですが、ご教授いただけると助かります

```
-(void)redChengeButton:(id) sender{
    NSLog(@"ボタンが押されました");
    NSRange selectedRange = self->tv.selectedRange;
    // 1文字以上を選択していたら
    if (selectedRange.length > 0) {
        NSLog(@"called if文");
        // attributedStringを取得して、Mutableにコピー。
        NSMutableAttributedString *theText = [tv.attributedText mutableCopy];
        // 選択部分だけ文字色を赤に変える。
        [theText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: UIColor.redColor range:selectedRange ];

        NSLog(@"my range is %@", NSStringFromRange(selectedRange));
        // 変更を加えたattributedStringを戻す。
        tv.attributedText = theText;

        UIFont *font = self->tv.font; // フォントを取得
        self->tv.typingAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor,
                                      NSFontAttributeName: font};
    }

}
```

```
//これで保存しようとするとエラー
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[ud setValue:tv.attributedText forKey:@"tv"];

//これだと色の変更が保存されない
 NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[ud setValue:tv.text forKey:@"tv"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)

ここから引用：

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing
>   common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A
>   default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData. For more details, see Preferences and Settings
>   Programming Guide.

ということで、`NSAttributedString`は、`NSData`に変換してから、`NSUserDefaults`に保存してください。

*NSDataに変換して、NSUserDefaultsに書き込み*

```
// attributedTextは、NSAttributedStringのインスタンス。
NSData *textData = [attributedText dataFromRange: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length) documentAttributes: @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType} error: NULL];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject: textData forKey: @"TextData"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

*NSUserDefaultsから読み出して、NSDataから変換*

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *textData = [defaults dataForKey: @"TextData"];
NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData: textData options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes: NULL error: NULL];
```

※Objective-C 1.0以来のクラシックな書式をお使いの方に対して、2.0のモダンな書式を使うのはどうかと思いましたが、ご容赦ください。例外発生などの対処はしておりませんので、適宜対応してください。

Comment: ありがとうございました！
正常に処理することができました。